# Merge two lines conditionally

Tags: bash, awk

```
200005251|AAAAAA
200005252|BBBBB
200005261|CCCCCC
200005262|DDDDD
200005292|EEEEEE
200005301|FFFFFF
200005302|VVVVVV
200005311|AAAAAA
200005312|JJJJJJ
200006011|LLLLLL
200006021|SSSSSS
200006022|HHHHHH
200006051|OOOOOO
200006052|GGGGGG
200006061|KKKKKK
200006062|FFFFF
200006071|TTTTTT
```

I have a file in first field as above. I need to merge every two lines if they only end ......1 and ......2. and leave the others as is. Desired output:

```
200005251|AAAAAA 200005252|BBBBB  
200005261|CCCCCC 200005262|DDDDD    
200005292|EEEEEE  
200005301|FFFFFF 200005302|VVVVVV  
200005311|AAAAAA 200005312|JJJJJJ  
200006011|LLLLLL  
200006021|SSSSSS 200006022|HHHHHH  
200006051|OOOOOO 200006052|GGGGGG  
200006061|KKKKKK 200006062|FFFFF  
200006071|TTTTTT
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if ($i~/1$/ && $(i+1)~/2$/) { 
                        printf("%s %s\n",$i,$(i+1)); i++; 
                    } else { 
                        printf("%s\n",$i) 
                    } 
                }' file
```

The output:

```
200005251 200005252
200005261 200005262
200005292
200005301 200005302
200005311 200005312
200006011
200006021 200006022
200006051 200006052
200006061 200006062
200006071
```

---

As you have changed your initial input - here's extended version:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                     if ($i~/1\|[[:alpha:]]+$/ && $(i+1)~/2\|[[:alpha:]]+$/) { 
                         printf("%s %s\n",$i,$(i+1)); i++; 
                     } else { 
                         printf("%s\n",$i) 
                     } 
               }' file
```

The output v.2:

```
200005251|AAAAAA 200005252|BBBBB
200005261|CCCCCC 200005262|DDDDD
200005292|EEEEEE
200005301|FFFFFF 200005302|VVVVVV
200005311|AAAAAA 200005312|JJJJJJ
200006011|LLLLLL
200006021|SSSSSS 200006022|HHHHHH
200006051|OOOOOO 200006052|GGGGGG
200006061|KKKKKK 200006062|FFFFF
200006071|TTTTTT
```

---

*Details*:

- `-v RS=" "` - treat space as record separator instead of newline
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all fields
- `if ($i~/1\|[[:alpha:]]+$/ && $(i+1)~/2\|[[:alpha:]]+$/)` - condition to check if current field has `1` at the end of its 1st section and next field has `2` at the end of its 1st section

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -nE 'chomp;
          if ($previous =~ /1$/ and /2$/) {
              say "$previous $_";
              $previous = "";
          } else {
              say $previous if $previous;
              $previous = $_;
          }
          }{ say $previous if $previous
         ' -- input
```

You keep the previous line in $previous. If it ends in `1` and the current line (stored in `$_` by `-n`) ends in `2`, you print both of them on the same line and clear the $previous; otherwise, you print the previous one if there's any, and store the current one in $previous. The last line prints the last number if it wasn't printed with the previous one.

Comment: This works but if it would be only one field. I have file with two fields seperated by "|"

Comment: So, try to modify it, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ num[NR]=$1 } END { for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (substr(num[i+1],length(num[i+1]))=="2") { printf num[i]"\t"num[i+1]"\n";i++ } else { print num[i] } }' nums
```

Where nums is the file with the data. First we put the data in an array called num then we loop through the array checking to see if the next element ends in two (using the substr function along with length to get the last character). If it does then we print both and add one to the counter else we just print the element.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `awk` script may achieve your goal,

awk_file:

```
{
  if($1%2==1) {
    if(odd==1){
      printf "\n";
    }   
    printf "%s ",$0;
    odd=1;
  } else {
    printf "%s\n",$0;
    odd=0;
  }
} END {printf "\n"}
```

Then execute:

```
$ awk -v FS='|' -f awk_file file
200005251|AAAAAA 200005252|BBBBB
200005261|CCCCCC 200005262|DDDDD
200005292|EEEEEE
200005301|FFFFFF 200005302|VVVVVV
200005311|AAAAAA 200005312|JJJJJJ
200006011|LLLLLL 
200006021|SSSSSS 200006022|HHHHHH
200006051|OOOOOO 200006052|GGGGGG
200006061|KKKKKK 200006062|FFFFF
200006071|TTTTTT
```

Comment: This is a better  and general approach. Can you explain in plain English how does this code works?

Comment: From the logic, print `$0\n` while the extracted numeric is odd, and print `$0` when it's even. And one more special rule, if last time is odd extracted, add an `\n` before print `$0`